# Is it possible to use afplay to open a URL instead of a file on disk?

Tags: audio, curl, url

I would like to use `afplay` to open a URL instead of a file.

The help page only says:

```
    Audio File Play
    Version: 2.0
    Copyright 2003-2013, Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Specify -h (-help) for command options

Usage:
afplay [option...] audio_file

Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis
  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
```

I tried piping cURL into it and setting `-` as the input file (which work with other commands) but it didn't succeed.

```
$ curl "https://server.com/file.ogg" | afplay -
unknown argument: -
```

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Nope, doesn't work :( Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `aplay` doesn't support piping input from stdin. One [ugly] workaround could be to grab the file, store it under `/tmp` and play ti from there:

```
$ curl -s https://server.com/file.ogg > /tmp/file.ogg && afplay /tmp/file.ogg
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to fall back to something like this... I was hoping to be able to stream something directly without downloading the whole file, but oh well... Thank you!

Comment: $ `afplay /dev/stdin < foo.mp3` # works but maybe bash is doing me a "favor"
$ `cat foo.mp3 | afplay /dev/stdin` # fails with
`Unspecified exception`

Comment: Probably pipes are seekable on macos when created by the shell with `<`

Comment: Indeed, behavior differs between the two syntaxes because pipes created with `<` are seekable. Test tool: https://pastebin.com/uxQg4bLL

Answer (score 1):

Afplay doesn't support streaming from stdin but what you can do is create a file descriptor and stream into that, and have afplay read from the file that you're streaming to.

Here's a working example streaming somafm radio:

```
exec 3<> /tmp/file.mp3 && curl -s http://ice1.somafm.com/defcon-128-mp3 2>&1 | tee >&3 | (sleep 1; afplay /tmp/file.mp3)
```

Comment: this only plays a few seconds